# Patch class property to return a modified version of the original value

Tags: python, python-unittest

I would like to patch a class property to return a modified version of the original property.

In this example, I would like to patch `Greeter.greeting` to prepend the value "TEST" to whatever the real `greeting` property returns:

```py
class Greeter:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def greeting(self):
        return f"Hi {self.name}"
```

I thought something like this might work:

```py
def test_greeter():
    with patch.object(
        Greeter, "greeting", new_callable=PropertyMock(wraps=lambda self: f"TEST {self.greeting}")
    ):
        greeter = Greeter(name="Some Person")
        assert greeter.greeting == "TEST Hi Some Person"
```

But this gives me:

```
TypeError: test_greeter.<locals>.<lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I've also tried various formulations such as:

```py
patch.object(Greeter, "greeting", wraps=lambda self: f"TEST {self.greeting}")
patch.object(Greeter, "greeting", side_effect=lambda self: f"TEST {self.greeting}")
```

but I'm having no luck.

Is this possible? It *feels* like it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You could just patch in a replacement descriptor, like this:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch


class Greeter:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def greeting(self):
        return f"Hi {self.name}"


def test_greeter():
    class FakeGreeting:
        def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
            return f"TEST Hi {obj.name}"

    with patch.object(Greeter, "greeting", new=FakeGreeting()):
        greeter = Greeter(name="Some Person")
        assert greeter.greeting == "TEST Hi Some Person"
```

The above test runs successfully:

```
============================ test session starts ============================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.6, pytest-7.2.2, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /usr/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/lars/tmp/python
collected 1 item

test_property.py::test_greeter PASSED                                 [100%]

============================= 1 passed in 0.02s =============================
```

I think that `PropertyMock` is only going to be useful with a static return value; for what you're doing, you need the property descriptor to be able to access the object to which it is attached.

Comment: Ah, I feared that might be the answer. It's a shame there's no mechanism for this that doesn't involve rewriting the property. It's OK in this very simple dummy case, but it's not what you'd ideally do because it involves writing (almost) the same code in the tests as exist in the code under test.